# How to stop a host from the client script?

Tags: unity, multiplayer, unet

I am developing a two player multiplayer game. Since its only two players, I don't want to keep my connection open if a player disconnects.

Now this works well from the host side, through usage of `StopHost()`. If the player who hosts disconnects, it disconnects both the players from the game.

But using `StopHost()` in the client(Player B) side does not remove the host player(Player A). In other words, the client is out of the game, but the host is still in the game.

**So, what I want is if one player(host or the client whoever it is) disconnects, I want both of them to be disconnected.**

So, how can I do it? Please help me with this. I have almost lost hope with UNET. Thanks

**EDIT:**

**My setup is like this, my LobbyManager comprises of UI elements like "TitlePanel", "MainPanel", etc.**  **The Disconnect button is part of the title panel and gets enabled on press of Esc key.** **The button is linked to a script attached to the "TitlePanel".** **This script uses a `MonoBehaviour` which I changed to `NetworkBehaviour` in order to use `[Command]`.** **But it doesn't work as my "Title Panel" does not have a `NetworkIdentity`. Adding one creates even more problems**

**So, I thought if there was a way to send mesages from client to server without NetworkBehaviour, then maybe I could send a flag there to the server.**

**So is it possible?**

Comment: Don't force the game to stop via code, just deal with requests to make sure *anyone* isn't allowed to play if there aren't at least two players

Comment: Now that's the problem. Both the host and the client are already in the game. And when the client leaves, host doesn't. For now, I either want the host to be sent back to the lobby scene and start waiting for a new player or atleast be disconnected and start over again. How to do that?

Comment: Also, I was wondering if and when a client disconnects, does it invoke any callback methods on the host? If so, I could try editing that method.

Comment: Ok. I think I know where I have gone wrong. I have edited my question. Please check

Answer (score 1):

On your custom NetworkManager you can override the OnServerDisconnect for that purpose. Your code should looks like this:

```
public override void OnServerDisconnect(NetworkConnection conn)
{
    NetworkServer.DestroyPlayersForConnection(conn);
    StopHost();
}
```

OnServerDisconnect means: on the server side a client has disconnected. I know, the method name does not suggest that :/

I also know that this is a question from 2016 but as it may still hunt people at night, I'll left this answer here. Cheers ;)